# homework: using a loop to verify that a file doesn't exist

Tags: java

```
              String filename1; //file name to write to

    //get the file name to write to 
    System.out.println("\nEnter the filename for the file where the information will be stored:");
    filename1=keyboard.nextLine(); 
              File title1= new File(filename1);

    while (title1.exists()) //make sure the file doesn't exist
    {
        System.out.println("The file " + filename1 +" already exists.");
        System.out.println("Please choose another name.");
        System.out.println("Enter the filename:");
        filename1=keyboard.nextLine();
    }
```

once the loop is triggered by a filename that exists it keeps reiterating even after entering a file name that doesn't exist. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always check first file if exist or not you should initialize it with the new file name

```
 File title1= new File(filename1);
 while (title1.exists()) //make sure the file doesn't exist
{
    System.out.println("The file " + filename1 +" already exists.");
    System.out.println("Please choose another name.");
    System.out.println("Enter the filename:");
    filename1=keyboard.nextLine();
    title1= new File(filename1);   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually testing the existence of a new file on each iteration, just testing .exists() on the title1 as it's instantiated prior to the loop, for every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because inside your while loop no where you are modifying `title1`.

Answer (score 0):

The loop doesn't exit because `title1` still points to the old file (the one that already exists). You need to update the variable:

```
String filename1; //file name to write to

//get the file name to write to 
System.out.println("\nEnter the filename for the file where the information will be stored:");
filename1=keyboard.nextLine(); 
File title1= new File(filename1);

while (title1.exists()) //make sure the file doesn't exist
{
    System.out.println("The file " + filename1 +" already exists.");
    System.out.println("Please choose another name.");
    System.out.println("Enter the filename:");
    filename1=keyboard.nextLine();

    title1 = new File(filename1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why?

Because you are not updating `title1`.  In fact, you keep on testing the first (non-existent) file name provided by the user.

---

There's another (rather obscure) bug in the code.  If the user enters the EOF character (e.g. ^D), a call to `readLine()` will return a `null`, and your code will then attempt to call `exists()` on a null reference ... resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
filename1=keyboard.nextline();
```

All you're doing is updating the string value held in `filename1`.  Even though you used `filename1` when creating `title1`, that relationship isn't maintained the way you may be thinking it is.

What you need to do is create a new File with the new filename, and do the same test again:

```
filename1=keyboard.nextLine();
// re-create file 1 with the new filename stored in filename1
```

Also it is generally nicer to store the control variable (the bit that says whether or not to continue doing the loop) in its own variable, rather than calling a method:

```
Boolean fileExists = title1.exists();

while(fileExists) {
    ....
}
```

Which will make your code look something like this:

```
filename1=keyboard.nextLine();
// re-create file 1 with the new filename stored in filename1
// update the fileExists variable to reflect if the new file exists or not
```